# How to stop scrolling on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-plugins

See my project inspiration:http://www.myprovence.fr/snapshots2012/en/marseille-provence/0-carte.html I am designing same scrolling for my project & using exactly same html structure & jquery plugins. But as an exception, I would like to pause scroll when user hover on white tip/rectangle bubbles. Any suggestion, how to stop scrolling on hover?

Comment: Hi Tushar, I have done exactly what ever its there on my website I have mentioned. Its doing good but I want that extra functionality on mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".spot").hover(function(){

_unactiveAutoRotation();

},function(){

var direction=domElmts.$nav.$navNext.attr('data-map-direction');
direction=domElmts.$navPrev.attr('data-map-direction');
_moveToDirection(direction);



});
```

Try the above code.

Comment: no its not working.. this is how I have implemented

$(".spot").hover(function(){

_unactiveAutoRotation();

},function(){

var direction=domElmts.$nav.$navNext.attr('data-map-direction');
direction=domElmts.$navPrev.attr('data-map-direction');
_moveToDirection(direction);

});